# How do I add a timer to my game?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a platformer game and when the player collects all of the coins they go to the next level, how would I add a timer on screen that when it gets to 0 the level restarts? This is the section of my code right now that handles if the player restarts the level if they touch lava.

```
Level.prototype.playerTouched = function(type, actor) {
  if (type == "lava" && this.status == null) {
    this.status = "lost";
    this.finishDelay = 1;
  } else if (type == "coin") {
    this.actors = this.actors.filter(function(other) {
      return other != actor;
    });
    if (!this.actors.some(function(actor) {
           return actor.type == "coin";
         })) {
      this.status = "won";
      this.finishDelay = 1;
    }
  }
};

function runGame(plans, Display) {
  function startLevel(n) {
    runLevel(new Level(plans[n]), Display, function(status) {
      if (status == "lost")
        startLevel(n);
      else if (n < plans.length - 1)
        startLevel(n + 1);
      else
        console.log("You win!");
    });
  }
  startLevel(0);
}
```

Comment: Check out the documentation for [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). You'll probably want to call it early in `startLevel()`. Don't forget to `clearTimeout()` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `setInterval`.

Here's an example code from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Using this as a sample you can create a variable with your time left, and decrease every call of the timer.

Something like this:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

var timeLeft = 10;

function myTimer() {

    if (timeLeft > 0){
         timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timeLeft;    
    }else{
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Game over";    
     }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but can't get it to work, when I do the timer is above the game and shows the actual time for a second before counting down, also I don't know how to make it reset the level when it gets to 0.